# When applying to a university do you apply to just the college or only the specific program/major you are interested in

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

For example: Do you apply to NYU or only Stern specifically (if you're doing business). Stern obviously has a lower acceptance rate than NYU itself.

Same for Wharton and UPenn.

Comment: check the university's admissions website

Comment: Are the people voting to close for out-of-scope assuming undergrad admissions despite the tag?

Comment: @Anyon - well, this varies from situation to situation, so depends on individual factors.

Comment: @JonCuster which is why I (and probably yourself) voted to close for depending on individual factors, not for being out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Every university in US sets its own policies with some exceptions for state systems. The early part of the admissions process is primarily administrative, collecting documents, and such. So, it depends on how they want to organize it. I'll let you explore it for specific examples as you can do it as easily as I.

Ultimately, though, the decisions are made at the department level, probably even below the "school" (i.e. Stern) level. The decisions are made somewhat based on capacity, faculty availability, funding, and such.

But, since most places now use web systems for applications, starting at the posted address will get you to the right place. For a university divided into "schools", as is NYU, you might look first for the web page of that school (Stern) and see what it says about admissions. If you don't find anything, look to the university web site. But any link you find should take you to the right place for your needs.

Comment: Decisions are made at the department level for graduate admissions, but not for undergraduate admissions.  It's not clear to me what the question is about.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, I depend on the tag [tag:graduate-admissions]. Yes, undergrad is different.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo - although even undergraduate admissions can be determined at a lower level. Where I did my undergrad, one had to supply additional materials to apply to the engineering school.

Comment: what about for undergraduate admission? How different is the process?

Comment: It might be the university level or (a bit less likely) the school level. But the online system will take you to the right place. Departments will give a general admissions system their needs and constraints and it will then be handled outside the department except, perhaps, in extreme edge cases (say, a 12 year old genius). But, again, every U is different in US. The system is also probably more based on numbers (GPA, ...) than the grad system.